# wait time between inserts in a sql script?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any option or order to wait a time between some inserts from a SQL script? For example.

If I've the following:

```
 INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user1', 'pass1');

 INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user2', 'pass2');
```

And I want to wait 1 second for example between this two inserts.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the [sleep function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep)?

Comment: um, not sure why you would want to, the script should just execute line by line and not progress until the previous line is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure there is, but two question come into mind: 1. Why? 2. Are you running these inserts from an application or PHP script? And if so, can't you build a delay there?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why would you want your SQL script to sleep?  P.S. If you are doing multiple inserts, I'd suggest using [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SLEEP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) function

```
select sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SLEEP(duration)` method like

```
 INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user1', 'pass1');

 SELECT SLEEP(10); -- sleep for 10 seconds

 INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('user2', 'pass2');
```